# java string matching with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a specific key i need to match.  The key is 10 set's of 4 separated by a dash.  The combination can be a combination of letters or numbers.

Example.

aa11-bb22-cc33-44dd-55ee-66ff-gg77-hh88-99ii-jj10

I just want to validate the pattern being 10 sets of 4 separated by a dash.

Probably match this via regex, but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The regex for this should not be difficult. Have you taken a look at the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){9}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/11

Comment: nice link ... didn't know something like that existed for regex testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){9}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}
```

Here's the regex in action: http://regex101.com/r/xR1wV3/1

Explanation:

1. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` --> any character from a to z, A to Z and 0 to 9
2. `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` --> `{4}` indicates exactly 4. So `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` means
   exactly 4 characters
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}`- --> add a dash (-) at the end
   to match for dash separators. This should match with `aa11-` for
   example
4. `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-)` --> put #3 into parenthesis
5. `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){9}` --> add `{9}` to the parenthesis to specify that this pattern repeat 9 times
6. `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` --> add a `[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}` at the end to match the last set of 4 characters (same as #2 above)

Comment: Using the tool that @vks posted: Here's my regex - either one works:
http://regex101.com/r/xR1wV3/1

Comment: I had added it as a separate comment but added it to the answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
(?!.*_)(\w{4}-){9}\w{4}
```

This makes use of the fact that `\w` means "any letter, number or underscore" and the negative look ahead prevents the underscore.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, I know that, but if you read my answer, you'll see that is not a problem because i use a negative look ahead to assert there are no underscores anywhere in the input. I used `\w` with the NLA to make the regex shorter over all.